# Group By in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group this dataframe by `ID` on the `Amount Column`:

[image]

The resulting group by statement should result in a table where `John's 10/21/15 amounts` are combined and `Jill`

[image]

The *Python* *Pandas* statement is not working for me:

```
dataframe['AUM'].agg(np.sum)
```

Comment: Please post text rather than images of your data as it makes it difficult for others to recreate your df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to actually call `groupby` on 'ID', 'Date' and 'Name' columns and then `sum` the amount and call `reset_index` to restore the indices back as columns:

```
In [39]:
df.groupby(['Date','ID','Name']).sum().reset_index()

Out[39]:
          Date  ID  Name  Amount
0  21-Oct-2015   1  John      14
1  22-Oct-2015   1  John      10
2  22-Oct-2015   2  Jill       9
3  23-Oct-2015   2  Jill      11
```